# My WiFi internet stalls when Laptop A is shut down

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

My WiFi internet stops working when a particular laptop is shut down or is not connected to the WiFi router.

My internet setup is like this:

- There is a Wimax device which provides internet connectivity and it's control panel is configured at address 192.168.1.1 and it operates with DHCP server enabled. The LAN cable from this Wimax device is connected to the LAN port of an ASUS DSL N10S router to share internet connectivity with multiple devices via WiFi.
- The WAN network of ASUS DSL N10S router is configured with VPI 8, VCI 35 with LLC Encapsulation in channel mode 1483 Bridged. The DHCP server in this router is disabled. It is configured at address 192.168.1.2

I am observing that when laptop A is shut down or disconnected from ASUS DSL N10S WiFi network, the internet connectivity to rest of the devices breaks. It is possible to access router control panel ( 192.168.1.2) , but it is not possible to access Wimax control panel (192.168.1.1)

Can any one guide me how to properly configure the router and wimax deivces so that any device connected to WiFi can access internet independent of connectivity of that laptop A?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you mentioning both WiMAX and DSL?

Comment: @Spiff what you mean? because they are two separate devices??

Comment: Are you getting Internet service via both a DSL line as well as via a WiMAX outdoor wireless link?

Comment: @Spiff Nope, the outdoor WiMAX unit is the only internet source. I connected the LAN cable from WiMAX to ASUS DSL N10S router to share internet via WiFi

Comment: Then why were you giving details of the DSL service configuration of the DSL box? It just makes the question confusing when you give irrelevant details, because it makes the reader struggle to try to figure out why those details are relevant.

Comment: @Spiff I thought DSL configuration may have affected it somehow..

Apparently, google is not loading on Windows 7 that I am using now no matter what. Beside that, downloads on my download managers stop suddenly, but loading youtube on Google Chrome fixes it for a few minutes. What is happening?

Comment: What is the IP address of your laptop A? What is gateway of other devices connected on network?

Answer (score -1):

Your Laptop A is actually acting as "Gateway" and probably DHCP server for your network.

From other PC/Device on network which become disconnected as soon laptop A shutdown check network configuration. Like Gateway/Nameserver etc.

I think you will find the problem.